# What's the Subject in 'What time is it?'

Tags: subjects, sentence

I'd like to know what part is the subject in the sentence 'What time is it?'.

Many thanks.

Comment: You try first. Hint: your example has subject-auxiliary inversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'it' is the grammatical subject (if you can speak of subjects with this use of the verb 'to be').

Now (as a noun referring to the present time) is what it implicitly refers to. But because of the various idioms surrounding the concept of time, and because the word 'now' is far more often used as an adverb of time than as a noun) you can't replace it with 'now'.

"Now is the time for peace." is (at least arguably) an example where 'now' is used as a noun.

... but ...

"Now it is three o'clock" uses 'now' as an adverb of time.

The ways we ask and tell about time on the clock are governed by compulsory idioms.

Think of the other way of asking the time (you sometimes hear it in BrE): "What's the time?"

In this case it's clear that 'time' refers to the present time.

So, in the unlikely event we wanted to, we might roughly translate "What time is it" into "What time on the clock is the present time/moment?"

And "It's ten o'clock" can be translated to "The present time is ten on the clock" ('o'clock' comes from 'of the clock', another way of saying 'on the clock').

That was fun (for me anyway, though I'm bracing myself for people wanting to contradict me)!

Answer (score 4):

The subject is "it".
But what is "it"? That question has no meaningful answer. Here, "it" is a "dummy pronoun", which is present in the sentence purely to satisfy the syntactical requirement for a sentence to have a subject. It doesn't actually refer to anything.

Comment: Yes; I would just add that the sentence contains subject-auxiliary inversion, where "what time" is predicative complement.

Comment: @BillJ May I ask you a little side-question? Which prepositions may be of a better use if one asks the other: "Could you tell me the time with your wrist-watch/the clock on the wall?" Or should it be "on your wrist-watch/clock" or "by your wrist-watch/clock"? Thank you.